# CasperJs won't navigate or find the download from the form submitted

Tags: forms, download, casperjs

I have prepared this casper js file to navigate a website, fill out a form, and generate the report that comes up.  The page that I would think it navigates to in order to download the report does not do anything, I am wondering what I can do to find the download.  I am not sure what that whole MIME part is in the google chrome console.  The require is not defined message does not appear when the code is ran by casperjs.  I put dd in all the links in the cmd console readout so that it didn't count as links

```
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to C:/Users/senes/Desktop/HTML/screenshots/test0.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to C:/Users/senes/Desktop/HTML/screenshots/test0.png
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form#frmavail'
[debug] [remote] Set "selRptGrp" field value to E8A69F22-18D8-4167-87AB-EACD5B97934B
[debug] [remote] Set "radTimeRange" field value to fixed
[debug] [remote] Set "selFixedRange" field value to 3
[debug] [remote] Set "optRes" field value to 1
[debug] [remote] Set "selRes" field value to 2~2
[debug] [remote] Set "init" field value to 2
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 8/9: done in 19764ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 9/10 htddtp://niu.resourcescheduler.net/resourcescheduler/ereports.asp (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 9/10: done in 19765ms.
[info] [phantom] waitFor() finished in 41ms.
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 10/10 htddtp://niu.resourcescheduler.net/resourcescheduler/ereports.asp (HTTP 200)
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form#frmavail'
[debug] [remote] Set "selReport" field value to 008BCFD8-E99A-4991-BE96-B867722767DF
[info] [remote] submitting form to ../CrystalReports/BuildReport.aspx, HTTP POST
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to C:/Users/senes/Desktop/HTML/screenshots/test.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to C:/Users/senes/Desktop/HTML/screenshots/test.png
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=htddtp://niu.resourcescheduler.net/CrystalReports/BuildReport.aspx, type=FormSubmitted, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] opening url: htddtp://niu.resourcescheduler.net/CrystalReports/BuildReport.aspx, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=htddtp://niu.resourcescheduler.net/CrystalReports/BuildReport.aspx, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to C:/Users/senes/Desktop/HTML/screenshots/testout.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to C:/Users/senes/Desktop/HTML/screenshots/testout.png
[debug] [remote] sendAJAX(): Using HTTP method: 'GET'
[debug] [phantom] Downloaded and saved resource in untitled.xls
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "htddtp://niu.resourcescheduler.net/CrystalReports/BuildReport.aspx"
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "about:blank"
```

[this is what the chrome console reports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehuQt.png)

```js
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
});

casper.start('http://niu.resourcescheduler.net/resourcescheduler/login.asp', 
   function() {
   // Wait for the page to be loaded
   this.waitForSelector('form#loginForm');
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo("we found the login");
    this.fillXPath('form#loginForm' , {
        '//*[@id="Email"]': 'hsc',
        '//*[@id="Pwd"]': '***********',
    }, true);
});

casper.thenEvaluate(function(){
   console.log("Page Title " + document.title);
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.waitForSelector('a[href="ereports.asp"]');
    this.click('a[href="ereports.asp"]')
});

casper.then(function() {
   // search for 'casperjs' from google form
    this.waitForSelector('form[name="frmavail"]');
    this.echo("it gets here");
    casper.capture('screenshots/test0.png');
    this.fillXPath('form#frmavail', {
       '//*[@name="selRptGrp"]': 'E8A69F22-18D8-4167-87AB-EACD5B97934B',
       '//*[@id="radTimeRange"]': 'fixed',
       '//*[@id="selFixedRange"]': '3',
       '//*[@name="optRes"]': '1',
       '//*[@name="selRes"]': '2~2',
       '//*[@name="init"]': '2',
    });
});


casper.then(function() { 
    this.waitForSelector('#selReport > option:nth-child(4)');
    this.fillXPath('form#frmavail', {
        '//*[@id="selReport"]': '008BCFD8-E99A-4991-BE96-B867722767DF',
    }, true );
    
    
    casper.capture('screenshots/test.png');
    
    this.on('navigation.requested',function(url,navigationType) {
    if (navigationType == 'FormSubmitted') {
        this.open(url);
        casper.capture('screenshots/testout.png');
        casper.download(url,"untitled.xls");
    }
    });
    this.removeListener("resource.requested");
    casper.download();
});

casper.run();
```